# How do I create a string with an appended number to retrieve it via a method?

Tags: c#

My goal is to create usernames that start with a "Z" and end with 000001 - 000048. I would like to store these in a list and then retrieve them to store in an Excel list. My code is buggy (FormatException), and so I am asking for assistance.

```
public static string GetUserName()
{
    int length = 5;
    int number = 0;
    List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 49; i++)
    {
        number = i;
        string asString = number.ToString("Z" + length); 
        userNames.Add(asString);
    }
    return userNames.ToString();
}
```

In this section I would like to save the generated user names to the Excel list

```
var login = new List<string> { GetUserName(), GetUserName(), GetUserName() };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-6.0) to format the usernames like below :

```
"Z" + i.ToString().PadLeft(length, '0')
```

The whole function could be re-written like this:

```
public static List<string> GetUserName()
{
    int length = 6;
    List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 49; i++)
        userNames.Add("Z" + i.ToString().PadLeft(length, '0'));

    return userNames;
}
```

If you notice, the return type of the function is corrected and removed some unnecessary lines. And to get the list of usernames :

```
var login = GetUserName();
```

**EDIT 2**

You can use this method which will return 16 user names when it is called :

```
public static List<string> GetUserName(int startFrom)
{
    int length = 6;
    List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = startFrom; i < 16 + startFrom; i++)
        userNames.Add("Z" + i.ToString().PadLeft(length, '0'));

    return userNames;
}
```

So if you need to call it 3 times, you can do it like below :

```
List<string> login;
for (int i = 1; i <= 48; i = i + 16)
    login = GetUserName(i);
```

It's similar to call the function 3 times like this :

```
 login = GetUserName(1);
 login = GetUserName(17);
 login = GetUserName(33);
```

Comment: My output is `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`
I need to call the method this way `var login = new List<string> { GetUserName() };`

Comment: The generated user name is transferred to my Excel list and saved in three cells. Therefore, I call the function three times. This happens in 16 workbooks, therefore 3x16=48. (Z000001 - Z000048)

Comment: The code itself works but how do I retrieve the 48 usernames in the list? With `var login = GetUserName();` I can only retrieve one username. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: It don't works for me as expected. Where i do implement the loop? In a separate method?

Comment: You can use that loop where you need. That's just the concept. Even you can call without the loop like `login = GetUserName(1);` which will return the list with 16 namse

Comment: Perhaps I have expressed myself wrongly. Only 3 user names are to be output per sheet. So, in the first sheet Z000048, Z000049, Z000050 and in the second sheet Z000051, Z000052, Z000053 etc....

Comment: Well, It seems a bit different issue you are telling now than the original post! But I told you the whole concept how it works and how you can implement this. Do you know how to debug in visual studio? I would suggest debug your program and identify where are you having issue now. We are here just to help you resolving the issue, not to do everything for you, you have to show your effort and the specific issue/error you are having, then we can help. You can post a new question to resolve the new issue.

Comment: I accept your answer anyway because it's the right one for the question in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look into PadLeft/PadRight.
ToString is a powerful tool, but PadLeft is the thing you are looking for I believe.

```
"Z" + number.ToString().PadLeft(myTotalStringLength, '0').ToString() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about changing your output of the function to what you want?

```
 public static List<string> GetUserName()
        {
            int length = 5;
            
            List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
            
            for (int i = 1; i < 49; i++)
            {            
                string asString = "Z"+ i.ToString().PadLeft(length, '0');
                userNames.Add(asString);
            }
            return userNames;
        }
```

then you can

```
var login = GetUserName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a number with 6 digits. Your code doesn't work because the `ToString()` method has a [standard numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and a [custom one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings), both which your format doesn't comply. You could use the `0` place holder to format a 6 digit number string and append the `Z` at the begining:

```
string asString = "Z" + number.ToString("000000");
```

You could also use string interpolation instead of append:

```
string asString = $"Z{number.ToString("000000")}";
```

Edit:

If you want a custom number of digits, you could initialize a string with the desired format:

```
string numberFormat = new string('0', length);
```

And use like this:

```
string asString = $"Z{number.ToString(numberFormat)}";
```

Edit 2:

You can also wrap `'Z'` in the format string, as long as it is between quotes or double quotes. Also, `number` in your code is useless since it's equal to `i`, so you can simplify with:

```
string asString = i.ToString("'Z'000000");
```